# How to retrieve sqlite with select statement and assign to vector then assign to a string

Tags: c++, sqlite

The following is what I had tried on getting vector pushback and what I lack of now is to assign it to a string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
    std::vector< std::vector < std:: string > > result;
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        result.push_back(std::vector< std::string >());

    if (sqlite3_open("abeserver.db", &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_prepare( db, "SELECT * from abe_account;", -1, &stmt, NULL );
                              //preparing the statement
        sqlite3_step( stmt ); //executing the statement

        while( sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 0 ) )
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
                result[i].pushback( std::string( (char *)sqlite3_column_text( st, i ) ) );
            sqlite3_step( stmt );
        }

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failed to open db\n";
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

Below is my database look on sqlite:

```
sqlite> select * from abe_account;
admin|Peter John|admin_account|password
```

I want to get the value "admin" & "password" together through sql select statement and then assign them to a string, how do i use vector to obtain this element [0] and element [3] to a string. as i need it for a if compareTo later on.

**Thanks for all the help !!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already pushing strings into your vector of vectors. Since you have organized your vectors as each row representing the same column value, if you want the strings for record `r`, you would do:

```
std::string username = result[0][r];
std::string password = result[3][r];
```